# Problem about partial derivatives from Bartle's text

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I have to show that the above equality holds under the stated conditions. I believe this is trivial but for some reason, I am missing something. I have tried taking partial derivatives but it has not helped me. This is an exercise from Bartle's Elements of Real Analysis. Can you give me a path to a solution?

Comment: Partial differentiation should always give you the usual one-variable derivative with the other variable treated as a constant.  We know from the chain rule that if $a$ is constant, then $\frac{d}{dt}\{f(at)\} = af'(at)$, right?

Comment: In both cases, you need the following version of the chain rule: if $G(x,y)$ is a function of two variables, and $f(t)$ is a function of one, then
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(G(x,y))=f'(G(x,y))\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}
$$

Comment: Thanks, I have that. My problem is showing equality. I thought I could use the theorem about equality of mixed partial derivatives to somehow justify that identity but it didn't help me.

Comment: @DougL You're overthinking it.  The chain rule tells you that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial\xi}=\eta f'(\xi\eta)$ for (a), and that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial\eta}=\xi f'(\xi\eta)$.  So $\xi\frac{\partial F}{\partial\xi}=\xi\eta f'(\xi\eta)=\eta\frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta}$.

Comment: Yep, I just realized that now, I'm sorry I'm in a rush to complete this assignment. thank you so much!